# Why sending function to a function is the same as sending function address?

Tags: c, function-pointers

There is one thing in C that always seems weird for me, when using function pointers in function argument why sending the function name is the same as sending the function address?

```
void bar(void (*functionPtr)())
{
    doSomething
}

void foo(void)
{
    doSomething
}

int main()
{
    bar(&foo);
    bar(foo); // why is this the same? In C logic it's not supposed to work
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Would you expect the entire function to be sent, the machine bytes?  The same reason you send the address of an array.  Copying is wasteful and time consuming.

Comment: C 2018 6.3.2.1 4 says “A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type “function returning *type*” is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning *type*”.”

Answer (score 0):

Because the `&` is automatic.  If you use the function name, it produces a pointer to the function.  If you read up on the language spec, you'll see that the `&` is optional here.

Comment: Okay, in the end it seems logic, as there is no case where you would want to send the function object

Comment: What do you mean, `&` is automatic?

Comment: I mean, if you leave out the `&` it does it anyway.  Like writing `+123` vs `123`, it's positive even if you don't mention it.